# How to get the mouse x and y positions separately

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make my first app in python, kivy and I need to be able to find out whether a specific button has been clicked, I thought to do it by checking with an if statement if the mouse is down, if the x and y positions are inside the button in the gui, but I can't seem to find a way to get the mouse x and y positions. touch.x returns the x, but I'd like the x in the 0-1 scale(I'm sorry I don't know what it's called)

```
    mainadd = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("Mouse Down", touch)
        if touch.x > 0.62 and touch.x < 1 and touch.y_ > 0 and touch.y < 1:
            self.mainadd.opacity = 0.5
```

This isn't what I need because the x and y don't stay the same as I resize the window.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: If you want values in a 0-1 scale (presumably 0-1 across the size of the window?), simply create them by dividing the pixel x/y position by the window width/height.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `touch.spos` for coordinates in the range 0-1. See the [Motion Event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent.spos) documentation.

Comment: Yes, I found that but how can I get the x and y coordinates separately, so I could write something like this: if x > 0.6 and x < 1 and y > 1 and y <0.6:     or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The `touch.spos` is a tuple. The 'x' value is `touch.spos[0]` and `y` is `touch.spos[1]`.